# Weak Sample Size & Low Statistical Power

Tags: dataset, sample-size, statistical-power, small-sample

I have a problem of sample size for my research paper approval. I could only ran the statistics on 5 subjects for both plantar pressure and temperature measurements but the statistical power seems to be weak. Even if I found significant correlations between temperature rise and dynamic pressure change in the experimental group.

According to literature some authors had a quite interesting approach in treating the data at foot level, so that when I consider one subject I get the data from both feet (10 feet). In this way one could overcome the problem of a weak sample size for the power estimation (from 5 to 10). Am I right? Would you suggest me to do the same thing? Feel free to ask me more details...

Comment: Your title says you have a "weak" sample size, but degree of "strength" is not an attribute of sample size. Would "small" be a better adjective for your title?